# An indexed set (for efficient removal in a vector)

Tags: c++, arrays

I was just about to implement my own class for efficient removal from an array, but thought I'd ask to see if anything like it already exists.   What I want is list-like access efficiency but using an array.  I want to use an array for reasons of cache coherence and so I don't have to continually be calling a memory allocator (as using std::list would when allocating nodes).

What I thought about doing was creating a class with two arrays.  The first is a set of  elements and the second array is a set of integers where each integer is a free slot in the first array.  So I can add/remove elements from the array fairly easily, without allocating new memory for them, simply by taking an index from the free list and using that for the new element.

Does anything like this exist already?  If I do my own, I'll have to also make my own iterators, so you can iterate the set avoiding any empty slots in the array, and I don't fancy that very much.

Thanks.

Note:  The kind of operations I want to perform on the set are:

1. Iteration
2. Random access of individual elements, by index (or "handle" as I'm thinking of it)
3. Removal of an element anywhere in the set
4. Addition of an element to the set (order unimportant)

Comment: How about [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)?

Comment: Thought about that but deque is fast for inserting/removing at either end, but not in the middle?  In the general case, I expect random access kind of usage pattern on the whole.

Comment: Added a note about that.

Comment: For the removal case: Is it allowed to change the _handle_ of another element during removal - e.g. by swapping the last element in a `std::vector` with the to be removed element and use `pop_back` afterwards for the actual removal? In this case, `std::vector` gives you all you need.

Comment: Can't change a handle, no.  As the handle is essentially the index of the item in the array and may be held elsewhere.

Comment: Be sure to measure what you do. Just using a vector and inserting/deleting is faster than a clever alternative in a surprisingly high number of cases...

Comment: Managing free indices sounds like a good idea. I don't think the standard library contains an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: jcoder you are right of course.  I know premature optimisation is a sin :).  I think my primary goal here is to avoid the mutex of a malloc or free, so any kind of dynamic scheme that doesn't pre-allocate nodes first would be a failure.  Which makes me think... a linked list where the nodes are pre-allocated.  Something like that?

Comment: How about something like a B-tree? Still not as fast as an array though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::list<T>` actually does sound exactly like the *theoretically* correct data structure for your job, because it supports the four operations you listed, all with optimal space and time complexity. `std::list<T>::iterator` is a handle that remains valid even if you add/remove other items to/from the list.

It may be that there is a custom allocator (i.e. *not* `std::allocator<T>`) that you could use with `std::list<T, Allocator>` to get the performance you want (internally pool nodes and then don't do runtime allocation everytime you add or remove a node). But that might be overkill.

I would start just using a `std::list<T>` with the default allocator and then only look at custom allocators or other data structures if you find the performance is too bad for your application.

Answer (score 1):

If maintaining order of elements is irrelevant, use swap-and-pop.

Copy/move the last element over the one to be removed, then pop the back element.  Super easy and efficient.  You don't even need to bother with special checks for removing the element since it'll Just Work(tm) if you use the standard C++ vector and operations.

```
*iter = std::move(container.back());
container.pop_back();
```

I don't recall if pop_back() invalidated iterators on vector, but I don't think it does.  If it does, just use indices directly or to recalculate a new valid iterator.

```
auto delta = iter - container.begin();
// mutate container
iter = container.begin() + delta;
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is it doesn't support operation #2 in the OP's list. What is the persistent index/handle to an object? Maybe I'm missing what you mean.

Comment: Ah, yes, you can form that with an additional layer that handles mapping indices to elements for that specific use case.  I generally call that a "slot map," articles online.  Usually one should just really think hard if they need that feature at all though; it might seem like a requirement but maybe isn't with some work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single array by storing the information about the "empty" slots in the space of the empty slots.

For a contiguous block of empty slots in your array `A`, say of `k` slots starting from index `n`, store `(k, n')` at location `A[n]` (where `n'` is the index of the next block of free indexes). You may have to pack the two ints into a single word if your array is storing word-sized objects.

You're essentially storing a linked-list of free blocks, like a memory-manager might do.

It's a bit of a pain to code, but this'll allow you to allocate a free index in O(1) time, and to iterate through the allocated indices in O(n) time, where n is the number of allocated slots. Freeing an index will be O(n) time though in the worst case: this is the same problem as fragmented memory.

For the first free block, you can either store the index separately, or have the convention that you never allocate `A[0]` so you can always start a free-index search from there.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` might be useful in your case.

Comment: std::map will eventually use operator new (malloc) when creating a new node, implying a mutex.  Seems quite heavyweight to me.